# How to get all subdocuments _id into variable

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Im trying to get families subdocuments _ids to variable.

Here my schema:

```
families: [
    {
      _id: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId
      },
      name: {
        type: String
      },
      relation: {
        type: String
      }
    }
  ]
```

the problem is, i can get the _id of parent to show inside variable, but when im trying to get the families _ids its showing `undefined` in console log.

What is the proper query to get families subdocuments _ids into variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this :

```
db.yourCollection.aggregate([
    { $unwind: '$families' },
    { $project: { Ids: '$families._id' } }, { $group: { '_id': '$_id', subDocumentsIDs: { $push: '$Ids' } } }
])
```

**Output:**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d58d3205a0d22d3c85d16f1"),
    "subDocumentsIDs" : [ 
        ObjectId("5d570b350e2fb4f72533d512"), 
        ObjectId("5d570b350e2fb4f71533d510"), 
        ObjectId("5d570b350e2fb4172533d511")
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d58d3105a0d22d3c85d1591"),
    "subDocumentsIDs" : [ 
        ObjectId("5d570b350e2fb4f72533d312"), 
        ObjectId("5d570b350e2fb4f71533d310"), 
        ObjectId("5d570b350e2fb4172533d311")
    ]
}
```

Please consider this as a basic example & go ahead with enhancements if anything needed, something like `$unwind` as an early stage would have performance impacts, if your collection is of large dataset, but you can easily avoid that by using `$match` as first stage, as you said you're able to get parent _id then use it in `$match` to filter documents

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, just back to code. it does work, im pretty new with NoSQL especialy mongo for my own project to learn MERN stack and this $unwind helps alot. Thankyou very much.